# Cannot parse simple CSV file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I'm trying to import this line:

```
"1","K&amp;M M&ouml;bel AG: Erstes Quartal: Plus 9%","Die K&amp;M M&ouml;bel AG, Kirchlengern steigerte ihren Umsatz im ersten Quartal um &uuml;ber 9% auf 68,1 Mio. Euro (1999: 62,3 Mio. Euro). Als Grund f&uuml;r die &uuml;berdurchschnittlich gute Entwicklung nannte der Vorstandsvorsitzende Volker Meurer das positive Gesch&auml;ft mit den f&uuml;nf wichtigsten Einkaufsverb&auml;nden, das um ein Drittel anstieg. Die Platzierung neuer M&ouml;belserien legte im gleichen Zeitraum ? ebenso wie der Auftragseingang ? um 13% zu.
```

using these lines:

```
csv_file = File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'db', 'seeds', 'news.csv'))
csv = CSV.parse(csv_file.read)
```

throwing me this error:

```
CSV::MalformedCSVError: Missing or stray quote in line 1
```

I went through this line a hundred times and can't find a problem. Any ideas?

**--- Update ---**

I'm using this query to do the

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    news
INTO OUTFILE '/Users/pbartels/Sites/moebel_fertigung/db/seeds/news.csv'
CHARACTER SET utf8
FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"'
TERMINATED BY ','
ESCAPED BY '\"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell it the separator you're using (since you're not using comma).

```
> CSV.parse(s, {:col_sep => ';'})
=> [["1", "K&amp;M M&ouml;bel AG: Erstes Quartal: Plus 9%", "Die K&amp;M M&ouml;bel AG, Kirchlengern steigerte ihren Umsatz im ersten Quartal um &uuml;ber 9% auf 68,1 Mio. Euro (1999: 62,3 Mio. Euro). Als Grund f&uuml;r die &uuml;berdurchschnittlich gute Entwicklung nannte der Vorstandsvorsitzende Volker Meurer das positive Gesch&auml;ft mit den f&uuml;nf wichtigsten Einkaufsverb&auml;nden, das um ein Drittel anstieg. Die Platzierung neuer M&ouml;belserien legte im gleichen Zeitraum ? ebenso wie der Auftragseingang ? um 13% zu. "]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the quotes and then check. It will work for you e.g.

1 ; K&M Möbel AG: Erstes Quartal: Plus 9% ; Die K&M Möbel AG, Kirchlengern steigerte ihren Umsatz im ersten Quartal um über 9% auf 68,1 Mio. Euro (1999: 62,3 Mio. Euro). Als Grund für die überdurchschnittlich gute Entwicklung nannte der Vorstandsvorsitzende Volker Meurer das positive Geschäft mit den fünf wichtigsten Einkaufsverbänden, das um ein Drittel anstieg. Die Platzierung neuer Möbelserien legte im gleichen Zeitraum ? ebenso wie der Auftragseingang ? um 13% zu.

Comment: Why remove? How will it now how to seperate?

Answer (score 0):

There is a " missing at the end of the line